# How many attacks should I have for Lv 10 Rogue using Broken Blade Stance, Two Weapon Fighting, & Rapid Shot?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

How many attacks should I have for Lv 10 Rogue using Broken Blade Stance, Two Weapon Fighting, & Rapid Shot?

I'm still getting use to the mechanics of [Path of War](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/). I love how useful the stance and maneuvers are. So here's what I got for current Lv 10 Rogue. (damages are upgraded with the feat [Startoss Style](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/startoss-style-combat-style/), and Shadow Assassin: Shuriken abilities via Rogue Talents, and I get a better range with the feats [Hawkeye](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/hawkeye-combat/) & [Far Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/far-shot-combat-final/))

**Rogue:** Lv 10
**BAB:** +7/+2
**Dex:** 20(+5) via level boost & **Crystal Shuriken** (via Metacreative Talent) is +12/+7 (this is just Dex and BAB for simple calculations)

with the following...

- > **[Metacreative Talent:](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-alternate-rules/psionic-traits/metacreative-talent/)** While you maintain psionic focus you can manifest shards of crystal as a swift action that last for one round. These blades can be used as thrown weapons if you use them immediately (you are proficient in their use; 1d2 slashing damage, 20/x2 crit, range increment 10 feet). This talent grants no benefit if you do not have the ability to gain psionic focus.
- > **[Broken Blade Stance:](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/disciplines-and-maneuvers/broken-blade-maneuvers/#TOC-Broken-Blade-Stance)** [...] may make an additional attack when making a full attack action. ***If the initiator is two weapon fighting, he gains this extra attack for both hands. The attack(s) uses the initiator’s full base attack bonus, plus any modifiers appropriate to the situation.***
- **[Rapid Shot:](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/rapid-shot-combat-final/)** +1 ranged attack with all attacks at -2 penalty
- **[Two Weapon Fighting:](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/two-weapon-fighting-combat-final/)** penalties attacking with two weapons are reduced, with light weapons main & off-hand -2 penalty.

OK so far

Rapid Shot & Two Weapon Fighting, I should get 4 attacks with Shurikens

+8/+8/+8/+3

But using Broken Blade Stance, If the initiator is two weapon fighting, he gains this extra attack for both hands. The attack(s) uses the initiator’s full base attack bonus.

So with out Rapid Shot I should get 5 attacks right?

+12/+12/+12/+12/+7 (Main-hand, Off-hand, Main-hand, Off-hand, Main-hand)

Cause it says with Two Weapon Fighting I get to attack twice at my highest attack bonus with both hands. How does Rapid Shot get added to the mix. Do I get the extra Ranged Attack it all attacks at -2 penalty?

+10/+10/+10/+10/+10/+5 (Main-hand, Off-hand, Main-hand, Off-hand, Main-hand, Main-hand)

But Broken Blade Stance says that the extra attack via Two Weapon Fighting is at Max BAB and other mods. Or do I apply the Rapid Shot penalty after the first 4 attacks to get the extra attack form Rapid Shot?

+12/+12/+12/+12/+10/+5 (Main-hand, Off-hand, Main-hand, Off-hand, Main-hand)

I hope you understand what I'm trying to ask. This guy is built as Shuriken Machine Gun

Comment: For reference, the errata coming Soon™ is going to drastically change that stance for balance reasons; it is considered far, far too strong by the *Path of War* development team.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit curious of how you got the Broken Blade Stance (which is 3rd level) with only levels in Rogue and already many feats spend elsewhere, and I'm also not sure you could generate an infinite number of shuriken with only one swift action, but, assuming everything works:

*(attacks in parenthesis are made with the off-hand)*

**Full Attack:** +12/+7

**With two weapons** (-2 on **ALL** attack roll, +1 attack at max BBA with the off-hand weapon): +10/+5/(+10)

**Rapid Shot** (-2 on **ALL** attack roll, +1 attack at max BBA): +8/+3/(+8)/+8

**Broken Blade Stance** (+1 attack per weapon at max BBA): +8/+3/(+8)/+8/+8/(+8)

The important detail in both two weapons fighting and Rapid Shot is that all attacks during this full-round attacks have a -2 penalty.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out how unlikely attacks at +8 are to actually *hit anything* at 10th level.

Comment: @KRyan Some of us, because of our absurdly bad luck, play spray and pray. At least then rolling three 1s in a row wastes only 3 *attacks* rather than 3 *turns*.